# discord.py I want to send out the title and name as a message

Tags: python

```
def checkPlayers(title, url, keyword):
    query = keyword.lower()
    doc = getDoc(url)
    rows = doc.select('tbody > tr > td > a')
    for row in rows:
        name = row.text.lower()
        if query in name:
            print(title, name)
```

I want to send out the title and name as a message.
But I still don't know how to solve this
if i change that to async def check players (title, url, keyword): the next line will not run
Is there a way for the disc bot to send the contents in the title and name in a message without using async def?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a message is async, so it must be done in an async function. You will need to change the function to async, or use something like `asyncio.create_task` if you do not care about the result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).